# Cloudera hadoop: not able to run Hadoop fs command and at same time HBase is not able to create directory on HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I have cloudera 5.0 beta cluster of 6 node up and running

But i am not able to view files and folders of hadoop HDFS using command

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -ls /
```

In output it is showing the files and folder of linux directory.

Although namenode UI is showing files and folders.

and while creating folder on HDFS getting error

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /test
mkdir: `/test': Input/output error
```

Due to this error hbase is not starting and shutdowns with following error:

```
Unhandled exception. Starting shutdown.
java.io.IOException: Exception in makeDirOnFileSystem
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseFileSystem.makeDirOnFileSystem(HBaseFileSystem.java:136)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.checkRootDir(MasterFileSystem.java:352)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.createInitialFileSystemLayout(MasterFileSystem.java:134)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.<init>(MasterFileSystem.java:119)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.java:536)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:396)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=hbase, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:224)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:204)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:149)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:4846)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:4828)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:4802)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:3130)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInt(FSNamesystem.java:3094)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3075)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:669)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:419)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:44970)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1002)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1752)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1748)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1746)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:90)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:2153)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2122)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:545)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1913)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseFileSystem.makeDirOnFileSystem(HBaseFileSystem.java:129)
... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=hbase, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:224)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:204)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:149)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:4846)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:4828)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:4802)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:3130)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInt(FSNamesystem.java:3094)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3075)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:669)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:419)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:44970)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1002)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1752)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1748)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1746)

at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1238)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:202)
at $Proxy27.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:164)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:83)
at $Proxy27.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:426)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:2151)
... 10 more
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `hadoop fs` command isn't picking up the namenode address from your `core-site.xml`.  Hadoop client code will generally default to the local file system in the absence of a configured namenode.

If you are running the command from a node on the cluster that isn't the namenode, you may have to tell CM to [deploy the client configuration](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/4.5.2/Cloudera-Manager-Enterprise-Edition-User-Guide/cmeeug_topic_5_9.html).

If you are running on a machine outside of the cluster, you'll have to set the configuration manually and make sure the `core-site.xml` file can be found somewhere in the Java classpath.

Comment: all the configuration files are managed by cloudera do you think it is good to edit the files?

Comment: Only edit the files yourself if you're using a machine that isn't managed by Cloudera manager. Otherwise, use the deploy command I linked to above.

Comment: thanks it worked i am able to resolve the error now ls command is working fine

Answer (score 3):

Either change the configuration of *core-file.xml* and edit the property *fs.default.name* as

```
<property>
     <name>fs.default.name</name>
     <value>hdfs://target-namenode:54310</value>
</property>
```

Or Run command like this

for cloudera

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -ls hdfs://<hadoop-master-ip>:8020/
```

for Apache Hadoop

```
bin/hadoop fs -ls hdfs://<hadoop-master-ip>:9000/
```

similarly you can run any command of hadoop fs

Comment: Excellent answer. The approach to specify hdfs://<ip>:8020 is very handy when trying to debug stuff, especially in the case of Cloudera!

Comment: Am using Apache Hadoop 2.7.2 and default port for me is `8020`, seems they are going the Cloudera way.